# For loop deletes files Instead of renaming

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a directory of files that I need to rename to a given string with a timestamp.

I use the following code:

```
for file in itvl_*
do
  mv "$file" "Interval_$(stat -c %Y "$file" | date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).Interval_001"
done
```

When I run the script in a directory of files that fit the given mask itvl_*, it removes all but one or two of the files and then successfully renames the last file in the group.

What might be happening here?

Comment: Your "seconds" isn't enough to differentiate files - bash is probably renaming most of all of the files in the same second, creating many files with the same file name.

Comment: `date` doesn't read from standard input; all you are doing is using the current date/time for the new file name. You want `$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S --date $(stat -c %Y "$file"))` to use the result of `stat` as an argument to `date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't delete all the files, it simple renames all of them to the same target name.

You can see it by running:

```
for file in itvl_*
do
    echo "Interval_$(stat -c %Y "$file" | date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).Interval_001"
done
```

The result is that they override one another and only the last one survives.